# Joining SQLite Tables

Tags: sqlite, join

I have below three tables as Mission1, Mission2 and Mission3 tables
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYV8n.png)

I want to join all these three table and result should look something as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HstG.png)

Below is the query which i tried but it is not working as expected

```
SELECT mission1_1.missionIdentifier, mission1_1.M1,mission2_2.M2,mission1_1.Timestamp 
FROM mission1_1 
INNER  JOIN mission2_2  ON mission1_1.timeStamp = mission2_2.timeStamp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you table names are Mission1, Mission2 and Mission3 and all 3 have columns MissionIdentifier, Mission_id and Timestamp then your query would fail because:-

- there is no table named mission1_1
- there is no table named mission2_2
- there is no M1 column in the table mission1 (assuming mission1 is the correct table name)
- there is no M2 column in the table mission2 (again assuming mission2 is the correct table name)

You query cannot produce anything near the expected results as the mission3 table is not joined.

Addressing the above issues then it would appear that you want the query to be :-

```
SELECT 
    mission1.missionIdentifier, 
    mission1.mission_id AS Mission_1,
    mission2.mission_id AS Mission_2,
    mission3.mission_id AS Mission_3,
    mission1.Timestamp
FROM mission1
INNER JOIN mission2  ON mission1.timeStamp = mission2.timeStamp 
INNER JOIN mission3 ON mission1.timestamp = mission3.timestamp
;
```

However, **this will not** produce the expected results. Instead for the data indicated (except missionidentifiers have been shortened, for brevity, to the first 2 characters of the data) then it will output :-

[image]

i.e. your select 2 rows from the mission1 table then adding extra columns from the single row in the mission2 table and then adding extra columns for the single row in the mission3 table and hence the 2 rows with all data as all rows have the same timestamp.

I suspect that what you want can be achieved by the following query, albeit it not in the order you have shown :-

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  mission_id,missionIdentifier, timestamp 
    FROM mission1 
    UNION SELECT mission_id,missionIdentifier, timestamp FROM mission2 
    UNION SELECT mission_id,missionIdentifier, timestamp FROM mission3
)
SELECT 
    cte.missionidentifier,
    cte.mission_id,
    mission1.mission_id AS mission1, 
    mission2.mission_id AS mission2, 
    mission3.mission_id AS mission3, 
    cte.timestamp AS timestamp
FROM cte 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mission1 ON mission1.missionidentifier = cte.missionidentifier 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mission2 ON mission2.missionidentifier = cte.missionidentifier
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mission3 ON mission3.missionidentifier = cte.missionidentifier
ORDER BY cte.mission_id ASC
;
```

Which produces/results in :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike it worked.

Comment: @s.kSyed that's good. If you believe that the above helper to answer you question then please tick it to show that it did help.